# Sequelize Transactions and Increments

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm having problem with `sequelize.transaction` and `model.increment`

I have this simple model

```
class Wallet extends Model {}

Wallet.init(
  {
    // Model attributes are defined here
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    availableBalance: {
      type: DataTypes.FLOAT,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: 0,
    },
  }
);
```

And I tried to do:

```
const wallet = await Wallet.findById(1);
await sequelize.transaction(async t => {
      //more sentences
      wallet.increment('availableBalance', { by: 1, transaction: t });
});
```

And that is failing with:

> Error: commit has been called on this
> transaction(6de20ad2-ab57-4038-9003-fabff6437449), you can no longer
> use it.

Note: Inside the transactions there are more sentences, but I left only the line that had conflict (The increment sentence)

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to wait async `increment` call:

```
const wallet = await Wallet.findById(1);
await sequelize.transaction(async t => {
      //more sentences
      await wallet.increment('availableBalance', { by: 1, transaction: t });
});
```

Comment: Oh god... how can I forgot that!!! Thank you.. It worked ;)

Comment: @Pipe I would recommend fetching the `wallet` using the transaction as well, otherwise it might be out of sync by the time you call `wallet.increment()`.

Comment: And since you are using `async/await` you can fetch the transaction like `const t = await sequelize.transaction();` and will need to explicitly call `await t.commit()` or `await t.rollback()` as needed.

Comment: And as one more note, the example in your question actually *would* almost work if you had returned it - you can return a promise without using `await` - but since you had other calls in the closure it was autocommiting before the `increment()` call could complete, this is why i can be helpful to do it explicitly though it is more verbose.

Comment: @doublesharp It's easier to use `await sequelize.transaction(async t => {` because you don't need to explicitly call `commit` or `rollback`. I suppose it's for more complicated scenarios.

Comment: Yup... I prefer to use transaction callback, so creating transaction and commiting transaction is done automatically.

Comment: @doublesharp But wallet.increment will not use the current model data. It will generate an update sentence with wallet id directly to the database. Somenthing like `update wallets set availableBalance = availableBalance + 1 where id = 1`. Or am I wrong?

Comment: In this exact case nothing wrong to get a wallet instance out of transaction scope. But it's recommended to work with the same records/models or linked ones in the same transaction to avoid any inconsistencies in data

Comment: @pipe it's unlikely, but it is theoretically possible for another process to update the available balance in the database and have the incorrect value be reflected in the model/view. Since you're working with wallets, I would usually go for consistency over performance. If you're using innodb it will only lock the row so shouldn't be much of a performance hit if any.

Comment: It's also true that `increment()` will use the column value, but if you make a different type of update to the same row it might overwrite a value that was written by another process (maybe adding a feature some time in the future), so it's often good form to select/update with the same transaction to prevent those accidental issues, at least in my experience.